# Wordpress. Dropdown menu disappears before cursor reaches next tab. Only when logged in

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

In Firefox and IE (not chrome)

When I'm logged in I am having an issue with my main menu on a website I am building. I lay my cursor on the a menu tab to have the tabs below it appear. I start down the tab with my cursor and the tab will disappear before I get to the next menu tab.

When i'm NOT logged in, it's absolutely fine.

It's fine in Chrome but not Firefox and IE.

The website is http://www.jobsarchitecture.com when you log in:

You can log in via:
user: test pw: test

Click on the 'Videos' menu and try and get to the following tab...

Really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to stop Event bubbling:

```
GLOBAL.Event.stopPropagation = function(e){
    e = window.event || e;
    if(document.all){
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }else{
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So where exactly would I place this?